# How can I find the value with the minimum MSE with a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, mean-square-error

My possible values are:

```
0: [0 0 0 0]
1: [1 0 0 0]
2: [1 1 0 0]
3: [1 1 1 0]
4: [1 1 1 1]
```

I have some values:

```
[[0.9539342  0.84090066 0.46451256 0.09715253],
 [0.9923432  0.01231235 0.19491441 0.09715253]
 ....
```

I want to figure out which of my possible values this is the closest to my new values. Ideally I want to avoid doing a `for` loop and wonder if there's some sort of vectorized way to search for the minimum mean squared error?

I want it to return an array that looks like: `[2, 1 ....`

Comment: What is this format of possible values? It looks like a dictionary

Comment: So there actually is no strict format, but yeah, we can make it a `dict` if need be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.argmin` to get the lowest index of the rmse value which can be calculated using `np.linalg.norm`

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]])
b = np.array([0.9539342, 0.84090066, 0.46451256, 0.09715253])
np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(a-b, axis=1))
#outputs 2 which corresponds to the value [1, 1, 0, 0]
```

As mentioned in the edit, b can have multiple rows. The op wants to avoid for loop, but I can't seem to find a way to avoid the for loop. Here is a list comp way, but there could be a better way

```
[np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(a-i, axis=1)) for i in b] 
#Outputs [2, 1]
```

Comment: I added some more detail to the question Specifically, I need this to work over MANY `new_values`

Comment: Does linalg.norm calculate MSE?

Comment: It calculates rmse which is essentially mse if you want to find the argmin.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your input data is a dictionary. You can then use NumPy for a vectorized solution. You first convert your input lists to a NumPy array and the use `axis=1` argument to get the RMSE.

```
# Input data
dicts = {0: [0, 0, 0, 0], 1: [1, 0, 0, 0], 2: [1, 1, 0, 0], 3: [1, 1, 1, 0],4: [1, 1, 1, 1]}
new_value = np.array([0.9539342, 0.84090066, 0.46451256, 0.09715253])

# Convert values to array
values = np.array(list(dicts.values()))

# Compute the RMSE and get the index for the least RMSE 
rmse = np.mean((values-new_value)**2, axis=1)**0.5
index = np.argmin(rmse)    

print ("The closest value is %s" %(values[index]))
# The closest value is [1 1 0 0]
```

Comment: I added some more detail to the question Specifically, I need this to work over MANY `new_value`s

Answer (score 0):

Pure numpy:

```
val1 = np.array ([
   [0, 0, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1, 1]
  ])

print val1
val2 = np.array ([0.9539342, 0.84090066, 0.46451256, 0.09715253], float)
val3 = np.round(val2, 0)
print val3

print np.where((val1 == val3).all(axis=1)) # show a match on row 2 (array([2]),)
```

Comment: This won’t work if my predicted value rounds to something that isn’t in the dict